# Inhomogeneous 2nd order differential equation - beats

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to determine the inhomogeneous and homogeneous equations of the equation below
$$my''+ky=\cos(\omega_2 t)$$
I found the inhomogeneous below where $\omega_1=\sqrt\frac{k}{m}$ (unsure if it's correct) 
$$c_2 \sin(\omega_1t) + c_1\cos(\omega_1t)$$
but I'm having difficulty finding the homogeneous equation. This is my working out
$$y_p(t)=a\cos(\omega_2t)+b\sin(\omega_2t)$$
$$y_p'(t)=\omega_2(-a\sin(\omega_2t)+b\cos(\omega_2t))$$
$$y_p''(t)=-\omega_2^2(a\cos(\omega_2t)+b\sin(\omega_2t))$$
I substituted $y''$ and $y$ into the original equation, rearranged to put the equation in terms of cos and sine and then solved for a and b ending up with values
$$a=\frac{-1}{m\omega_2^2+k}, b=0 $$
I'm pretty sure this is incorrect as I need to end up with a $\omega_1$ term and the next question asks to find initial conditions so that the inhomogeneous equation can be written in the form
$$y(t)=\cos(\omega_1t)+\cos(\omega_2t)$$

Comment: Is $\omega_2$ given?

Comment: Also, $a$ should be $\dfrac{1}{k - m\omega_2^2}$, provided $\omega_2\neq\omega_1$.

Comment: $\omega_2$ is not given, how does $a = \dfrac{1}{k - m\omega_2^2}$?

Comment: When you substitute your $y_p''(t)$ into the given differential equation and equate the coefficient of $\cos(\omega_2 t)$, you get $m(-\omega_2^2a) + ka = 1$, or $a\left(-m\omega_2^2 + k\right) = 1$.

Comment: So I end up with a general solution of $A\cos(\omega_1t)+B\sin(\omega_1t)+\frac{1}{k-m\omega_2^2}\cos(\omega_2t)$?

Comment: Yes and as you can see the particular solution $y_p(t)$ blows up if $\omega_2 = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} = \omega_1$, the natural frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to nonhomogeneous second order ODE is obtained by adding the solution to the homogeneous equation $y_c$ and the particular solution $y_p$, i.e. 
$$ y = y_c + y_p. $$

Answer (score 0):

First, you're mixing up "homogeneous" and "inhomogeneous."  Your second displayed line is the homogeneous solution.  When you try to find the non-homogeneous particular solution $y_p$, there are two cases.  If $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$, then what you did was correct (up to the correction given by @Chee Han.)  But if $\omega_1=\omega_2$, then you have to multiply your form for $y_p$ by $t$ before you plug it into the DE to find $a$ and $b$.